# bash scripts hyphen operator and square brackets

Tags: bash, shell, unix, operators, getopts

Please could someone tell me what is the hyphen operator in below scripts?

```
[ "${MYDATA_OPT-}" ] && set "$MYDATA_OPT" "$@"

data=${MYDATA_VER-1}
```

Is there some quick documentation of these operators?

I am also trying to understand below scripts

```
shift $(($OPTIND -1))
```

and

```
while getopts vhx: c; do
    case "$c" in
            v) let data=data+1 ;;
            h) usage ; exit 0 ;;
            x) . $OPTARG ;;
            \?) usage ; exit 2 ;;
            *) usage ; exit 2 ;;
    esac
done
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Tip - Once you figure it out, put a comment in the code explaining it!  Always think of the person that will be maintaining the code after you.  If the original writer had done that, it would have saved you time, right?

Comment: agree.. I am trying to retire this legacy code and trying to write new code. I will make sure i add comments to help others :)

Comment: This is a fairly regular, although not widely known, feature of the POSIX shell. Actually documenting it in a comment is not unlike adding "# Adds to the variable" to a line like `i++`. I'm all for commenting tricky patches of logic, but not language syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The form quoted in the `bash` man page under Paremeter Expansions

> 3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion
>
> **${parameter:-word}**
>
> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is substituted.
>   Otherwise, the value of parameter is substituted.

producing

```
${MY_DATA_VER:-1}
```

would expand to `1` if `MY_DATA_VER` was either unset, or set to the empty string. Your example, however, omits the colon:

```
${MY_DATA_VER-1}
```

This is also documented in the man page, although rather obliquely in a single sentence just before the specific operators are documented (from the 4.1 man page):

> Omitting the colon results in a test only for a parameter that is unset.

So in your example, the expansion produces `1` if `MY_DATA_VER` was never set, or whatever value `MY_DATA_VER` has (which could be the empty string) if it is set.

---

The `shift` example simply removes the first `$OPTIND-1` shell arguments. For the significance of `OPTIND` and a description of how `getopts` works, consult the `bash` man page or try `help getopts` at the `bash` prompt.